# How to render data from a different table in hasMany relationship Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

On a [jobs site](https://employbl.com/) I'm making I have a table for users, candidate_skills and skills. A user has many candidate_skills. Each candidate_skill belongs to a user and also belongs to a skill.

The **candidate_skills** table has these columns:

```
id
user_id 
skill_id
years_xp
comfort_level
created_at
updated_at
```

The **skills** table has an

```
id
name
...
```

Each user can pick a skill from from the skills table. That record gets added as a candidate_skill.

I am rendering a list of users and I'd like to render the skills that each candidate has. On my user model I have a method to grab a user's candidate_skills:

```
public function skills()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\CandidateSkill');
}
```

How do I populate this list with the names of the skills from the skills table?

Right now I'm grabbing the results like:

```
$candidates = User::whereIn('department_id', $departmentFilters)
            ->whereIn('work_authorization', $workAuthFilters)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->with('skills')
            ->get();

return response()->json($candidates);
```

This loads the list of candidate_skills but doesn't include a readable name for what the skill is. The result of the above query gives `$candidate->skill` like:

```
{ "id": 22, "user_id": 43, "skill_id": 64, "years_xp": 2, "comfort_level": null, "created_at": "2019-04-15 18:51:14", "updated_at": "2019-04-15 18:51:14" }
```

How can I include the name of the skill when rendering the candidate_skills for a user?

For example, **skill** with id of 64 has a name "PHP". When displaying user 43 I'd like to list out their skill with the name "PHP" instead of 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Skill;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The skills that belong to the user.
     */
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'candidate_skills', 'user_id', 'skill_id' )->withPivot('years_xp', 'comfort_level');
    }
}
```

and Skill model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Skill extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the user.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'candidate_skills', 'user_id', 'skill_id' )->withPivot('years_xp', 'comfort_level');
    }
}
```

Now, to get users with `department_id` and `work_authorization` filters

```
$candidates = User::whereIn('department_id', $departmentFilters)
            ->whereIn('work_authorization', $workAuthFilters)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->with('skills')
            ->get();
```

and while displaying in blade

```
@foreach($candidates as $candidate)
    @foreach ( $candidate->skills as $skill )
        {{ $skill->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($candidates as $candidate)
    @foreach ( $candidate->skills as $skill )
        {{ $skill->pivot->years_xp}}
        {{ $skill->pivot->comfort_level}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have no demo data to test it, but I guess it will work fine.

Comment: Awesome I had not used a pivot table before. Works great! Thank you

Comment: @ConnorLeech I am glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Many to many relationships in laravel need both models to have `belongsToMany`.
By default laravel will look for the `candidate_skills` table and will expect a `candidate_id` and `skill_id` column.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

### Candidate model

```
function skills() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class);
}
```

### Skill model

```
function candidates() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class);
}
```

Then you should be able to grab either model and get the related data.

```
$skills = Skills::with('candidates')->get();
foreach($skills as $skill) {
    foreach($skill->candidate as $candidate) { 
        echo $skill->candidate  
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'skills.user_id'`. The skills table does not have a user id column. I have the user_id on the candidate_skills table

Comment: You will need to access the pivot table, `$skill->pivot->user_id` or `$skill->user->id`